# Nonexistence of stable random variables

Tags: pr.probability

Is there an "elementary" proof that $\alpha$-stable random variables only exist for $0 < \alpha \le 2$?  By elementary I mean without using Fourier transforms.  I'd be happiest with either a direct probabilistic argument, or a geometric argument, e.g., referring to embeddings of $L_p$ spaces (as long as it doesn't depend on results which are themselves proved via Fourier analysis).

Note that what I'm interested in here is the fact that $\alpha$-stable random *don't* exist for $\alpha > 2$, not the fact that they *do* exist for $\alpha \le 2$.

**Edit:** To clarify, for the purposes of this question I define an $\alpha$-stable random variable as follows.  Given $\alpha > 0$, $X$ is $\alpha$-stable if, whenever $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ are independent copies of $X$, there is a real number $d=d(n)$ such that $X_1 + \cdots + X_n$ has the same distribution as $n^{1/\alpha} X + d$.  And I'm quite happy to simplify to the situation when $d=0$.

Comment: Stable distributions are essentially defined by their characteristic function, so to request a proof that side-steps the cf (Fourier transform) seems a bit unreasonable.

Comment: @wolfies: Definition: $X$ has a stable distribution if, whenever $Y$ is an independent copy of $X$ and $a$ and $b$ are real numbers, there are real numbers $c$ and $d$ such that $aX + bY$ has the same distribution as $cX + d$.  No characteristic functions in sight.

Comment: I would say this is the "real" definition of a stable distribution.  Versions given in terms of characteristic functions are only stated that way because the cf is the usual technical tool used to study them.

Comment: So where is the parameter $\alpha$ in your definition? And if it does not even appear in your definition, how do you propose to impose the constraint $0 < \alpha \leq 2$.

Comment: @wolfies: Good point.  Definition: $X$ has an $\alpha$-stable distribution if, whenever $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ are independent copies of $X$, there is a real number $d$ such that $X_1 + \cdots + X_n$ has the same distribution as $n^{1/\alpha} X + d$.

Comment: Now one could ask the question, how do you prove that a stable distribution (as I defined it) must be $\alpha$-stable for some $\alpha$?  But here I'm not interested in that; I really want to start with $\alpha$-stable distributions as I defined them above.

Comment: Good question.  If $\alpha$ stable variables exist and have finite $p$-th moment, then $\ell_\alpha$ embeds isometrically into $L_r$ for all $0<r\le p$.  So $\alpha \le 2$ because $L_r$ has cotype $2$ for $r\le 2$ and $\ell_\alpha$ does not.  But why must an $\alpha$ stable variable have finite $p$-th moment for some $p$?

Comment: @BillJohnson: That's a nice reduction.  It becomes even nicer if you can take $p=2$, in which case you could even replace the (easy) facts about cotype with just the (utterly trivial) parallelogram identity.

Comment: Here's a purely probabilistic proof that if nonzero $\alpha$-stable variables with finite second moment exist then $\alpha = 2$.  Suppose that $X$ is $\alpha$-stable with finite second moment, and assume without loss of generality that $X$ is symmetric, so that $\mathbb{E} X = 0$.  Then
$$
\mathbb{E} X^2 = \mathbb{E} \left(n^{-1/\alpha} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i \right)^2 = n^{-2/\alpha} \left(\sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb{E} X_i^2 + \sum_{i\neq j} \mathbb{E} X_i X_j \right)
= n^{1-2/\alpha} \mathbb{E} X^2,
$$
and so $\alpha = 2$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe there to be a proof avoiding Fourier analysis in the literature given by Feller (1971) as part of Theorem VI.1.1.

The argument can be subdivided into two parts. The first part (which was already mentioned in the comments) states, that if an $\alpha$-stable random vector has a finite non-zero variance, then $\alpha=2$. The second part is showing that variance is finite when $\alpha>2$, which is done by subdividing the integral $E(X^2)$ into a suitable series. Thus, $Var(X)=0$ when $\alpha>2$, which completes the proof.

Comment: I think I really should just read Feller straight through one of these days.